# Issues migrating a CentOS 4 xen guest to VMWare

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, vmware-esxi, xen

I am migrating a xen guest. It is running a CentOS 4. I am using the same steps that have worked in the past for our RHEL5 and RHEL6 based systems but for some reason, I'm getting errors.

Here are the steps in brief:

1. On the guest, install a non-xen kernel and the kernel's devel package.
2. Turn off database and other services that may cause data inconsistencies
3. Using VMWare vCenter Converter, migrate data to VMWare
4. Boot into rescue mode using CentOS 4.8 CD disc 1
5. Change root to the OS' root mount that rescue mode creates: `chroot /mnt/sysimage`
6. Modify `/etc/grub/grub.conf` so that the non-xen stanza is default
7. Remove non-xen modules from config: `sed -i.pre-vmware '/xen/d' /etc/modprobe.conf`
8. Check `/etc/inittab` and remove `co` runlevel and make sure we have lines for other runlevels
9. Double check `/etc/inittab` to make sure the Converter configured it correctly
10. Re-install grub: `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`
11. Finally, recreate init ram disk: `mkinitrd -v -f /boot/initr<kernel version>.img <kernel version>`

This is what I get when I reboot now:

[image: Kernel panic]

Can anyone help? Or provide some some troubleshooting tips? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Red Hat [KBase article](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/267403) discussing this issue and a solution.  Essentially it looks like you do not have the right storage drivers for your disks.  Be sure to include the scsi drivers when you make your initrd image:

```
# mkinitrd -f -v --with=scsi_mod --with=sd_mod --with=mptbase --with=mptscsi --with=mptspi --with=mptsas --with=mptscsih /boot/initrd-<version>.ELsmp.img <version>.ELsmp
```

Comment: That did it! I added `scsi_mod` and `sd_mod` before but that wasn't sufficient apparently. Thanks!